# How can I check multiple textboxes if null or empty without a unique test for each?

Tags: c#, arrays, testing, text, isnullorempty

I have about 20 text fields on a form that a user can fill out. I want to prompt the user to consider saving if they have anything typed into any of the text boxes. Right now the test for that is really long and messy:

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbxAfterPic.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbxBeforePic.Text) ||
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(splitContainer1.Panel2) ||...//many more tests
```

Is there a way I could use something like an Array of any, where the array is made of the text boxes and I check it that way? What other ways might be a very convenient way in which to see if any changes have been made since the program started?

One other thing I should mention is there is a date time picker. I don't know if I need to test around that as the datetimepicker will never be null or empty.

EDIT:
I incorporated the answers into my program, but I can't seem to make it work correctly.
I set up the tests as below and keep triggering the Application.Exit() call.

```
        //it starts out saying everything is empty
        bool allfieldsempty = true;

        foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            //checks if its a textbox, and if it is, is it null or empty
            if(this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Any(t => string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Text)))
            {
                //this means soemthing was in a box
               allfieldsempty = false;
               break;
            }
        }

        if (allfieldsempty == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Consider saving.");
        }
        else //this means nothings new in the form so we can close it
        {                
            Application.Exit();
        }
```

Why is it not finding any text in my text boxes based on the code above?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Sure -- enumerate through your controls looking for text boxes:

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c is TextBox)
    {
        TextBox textBox = c as TextBox;
        if (textBox.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            // Text box is empty.
            // You COULD store information about this textbox is it's tag.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For me, it does not recognize "this.Controls". Is there some import that needs to be done first? Tried "using System.Windows.Forms;" already.

Answer (score 13):

Building on George's answer, but making use of some handy LINQ methods:

```
if(this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Any(t => string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Text)))  
{
//Your textbox is empty
}
```

Comment: Side note: A standard out-of-the-box TextBox control will never return a null value in it's text property.  Nice use of LINQ though! +1

Comment: Your answer is better as it would throw the message box only once. 'Foreach' statement will throw MessgeBox.Show("Please enter all info") multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void YourFunction(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string[] txtBoxArr = { textBoxOne.Text, textBoxTwo.Text, textBoxThree.Text };
    string[] lblBoxArr = { "textBoxOneLabel", "textBoxTwoLabel", "textBoxThreeLabel" };
    TextBox[] arr = { textBoxOne, textBoxTwo, textBoxThree };

    for (int i = 0; i < txtBoxArr.Length; i++)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtBoxArr[i]))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(lblBoxArr[i] + " cannot be empty.");
            arr[i].Focus();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```