# Check which dynamically created textbox is empty

Tags: c#, winforms

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750290/how-can-i-check-multiple-textboxes-if-null-or-empty-without-a-unique-test-for-ea) provides a solution for checking if any textbox on a window form is empty.  My question extends to: if the textbox are dynamically created, is there a way to tell which textbox is empty **and return the control (textbox)'s name?**

Please advise if more info is required, thanks.

EDIT: codes: (the entire program is too large, I will add only the Text box portion)

```
        private TextBox Department_Contact = new TextBox();
        this.Department_Contact.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(lct1, lct2);
        this.Department_Contact.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(s1, s2);
        this.groupBox2.Controls.Add(this.Department_Contact);
```

This textbox loads depends on some comboBox selection; thus hardcoding

```
 if (Department_Contact.Text == string.Empty)
```

is not a choice for my code

EDIT:  Here's the complete answer for those looking for solution:

```
        Department_Contact.name = "Department_Contact";
        var txt = View.groupBox2.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToArray();

        foreach (TextBox t in txt)
        {
            if (t.Text == "")
                Console.WriteLine(t.Name);
        }
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using to create your textboxes?

Comment: The accepted answer in the linked question does it for *any* control regardless of it being dynamically added or not.

Comment: @Ben I will add the codes in a bit.

Comment: @poke I understand but is there a way to **return the contorl's name**?

Comment: [Control.Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.name.aspx) ([WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.name.aspx)) maybe?!

Comment: @poke only in WPF not window forms?

Comment: There are two links there. Control.Name is the first and (WPF) is the second link (not needed for your case)

Comment: In your case `Department_Contact.Name` is empty string, so to use it later you should set some name to it first.

Comment: @Dialecticus thanks, I guess the code I have does not automatically set the name = "Department_Contact".  How would you do it by the way?

Comment: Since I don't have enough information I'd say one way to do it would be like this: `Department_Contact.Name = "Department_Contact"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do, is pass all the textboxes into an array, then check each one.

```
var txt = this.groupbox.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToArray();

foreach (TextBox t in txt)
{
    if (t.Text == "")
        Console.WriteLine(t.Name);
}
```

`View` is a reference to the form. If you are doing this code in the form itself, you can use `this` instead.

Comment: View.Controls returns an error saying System.Windows.Forms.View does not contain a def for 'Controls'.  I will look it up on Google and let you know

Comment: @Alex You mentioned the textboxes were in a groupbox? If so, that will work (I'll change my code)

Comment: tried groupbox as GroupBox and my groupbox's name, which is groupBox2, the error happens on the groupbox now

Comment: I edited the question.  I have a meeting now and cannot get back here for a while, I will update asap, thanks all!

Comment: @Alex, ok, your problem seems to be occurring from my misleading code, I apologise for that. In my code **`View`** was a reference to the form. Since you appear to be doing the code *in* your form, you will need to use **`this`** instead. I have changed my code sample to match.