# If else statement textbox error

Tags: c#

I am trying to create an if else statement to show a message box if no input.

```
If(textbox1.text==false)
{
   messagebox.show("please fill in the boxes")
}
```

I have 16 different text box currently out, do i need to use an if else statement for each?

Comment: windows or web application ?if web try to use jquery or javascript.

Comment: So many answers and effort for such a basic question that has been solved before in a hundred ways??? I upvoted Fabio for referance to handles doubles and ect, but frankly this question is programming 101 and what any textbook or tutorial can help you with - not worth more effort as already so much similar on stackoverflow and elsewhere. There are 2 questions here, empty or null check and handling multiple elements with single line of code - ie. iterator. These have been answered so well before that they dont need yet another no-sign-of-any-prior-effort question on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass all `TextBoxes` in the list and loop it

```
//Create list once in the constructor of main form or window
List<TextBox> list = new List<TextBox>()

//...
list.Add(textbox1);
list.Add(textbox2);'
//...

Then loop it

foreach(TextBox txt in list)
{
    if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt.Text))
    {
        messagebox.Show("please fill in the boxes");
        break;
    }
}
```

**Update**
If all textboxes expecting only number/double input then use `TryParse` for checking if value is valid

```
foreach(TextBox txt in list)
{
    Double temp;
    if(Double.TryParse(txt.Text, temp) == true)
    {
        //save or use valid value 
        Debug.Print(temp.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        messagebox.Show("please fill in the boxes");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: List<TextBox> list = New List<TextBox>() i am getting an error on the "new" area

Comment: @KodySnow its "new" , not "New". C# is case sensitive regarding keywords :P

Comment: @KodySnow it is case sensitive also IsNullOrWhiteSpace has to be called with textbox's text --> it will be String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt.Text)

Comment: @Nikita thank you it all seems to be working now! Now to figure out how to write up the "else" with a variable of double type!  Thank you again

Comment: @KodySnow Welcome.you might want to use intellisense that will possible guard you from case sensitive keyword , press Ctrl+space in the writing area, the environment will suggest you a list of valid keywords & variables. Also, you can mark one post out of these as answer(whichever helped you the most)  by clicking on the outlined tick below the up-down vote buttons

Comment: @Nikita, any chance you can point me in the direction for double type? Else, calculate the total price by add the products of prices and quantities. Create a
variable of double type. Add all the prices of the products and assign them to the
created variable (it is assumed that the user will enter valid values, so there’s no check
for the validity of the inputs).

Is what im working on now and my book just isnt helpful

Comment: @KodySnow - do you want to have only numeric values in the textBoxes?

Comment: @Nikita yes, i am building a basic application that calculates inputs of both price and quantity. It doesnt give me any numbers, so i am assuming it is saying for all possible numbers which is confusing me.

Comment: @KodySnow take a look at this one for your textboxes-  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967558/only-allow-two-digits-after-decimal-in-textbox and then you can use Convert.ToInt32 or Convert.ToDouble() for later calculation.

Comment: @Nikita thank you, i am unable to post another question for 4 days and my rep is too low to chat. I believe i have the right code for the calculations do you mind if i email you the code?

Comment: @KodySnow feel free to reach me :) I have my ID added in my profile.

Answer (score 2):

You can not compare string with Boolean. textbox.text is a string data type.
try this, if you want to show different message for different textbox, you must use if-else statement for all texboxes.

```
If(textbox1.text=="")
{
messagebox.show("please fill in the boxes")
}
```

or

```
If(string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.text) == true)
{
    messagebox.show("please fill in the boxes")
}
```

for `multiple textbox` validation

Adding the handler to the textboxes is easily done with a foreach loop in the form constructor:

```
foreach(TextBox tb in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(x => x.CausesValidation == true))
{
    tb.Validating += textBox_Validating;
}
```

use `validating` event to handle it

```
private void textBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox currenttb = (TextBox)sender;
    if(currenttb.Text == "")
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Empty field {0 }",currenttb.Name.Substring(3)));
        e.Cancel = true;
    else
    {
        e.Cancel = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: awesome! So i guess i was confusing the "false" statement. Will i have to do that line each time for all 16 of my boxes or is there a universal "textbox" i can use

Comment: @KodySnow You can also use foreach as NonExistent answered. But if you want show specific message as per textbox you must manually check.. plz wait.. I am updating my answer.

Answer (score 2):

String and Boolean aren't comparable, also you can check if all the textfields are empty like described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8750290/3809894)

```
if(this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Any(t => string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Text)) {
    //Textfield is empty
}
```

Comment: I would not consider this ,since I might have hundreds of controls in my screen. running such a huge loop is definitely a downfall.

Comment: Hmm you're right, but @BhavikPatel did a great job filtering it in his answer,

Comment: You actually cast your `c` into `TextBox` two times here. You could cast it only once using `as` keyword and null-checking afterwards: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have a type mismatch error in your question. The `Text` property of a `TextBox` is of `string` type, while the keyword `false` is of `bool` type. You can read more on types in [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173104.aspx).
The fix to this issue would be:

```
If (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text))
{
    Messagebox.Show("please fill in the boxes")
}
```

Secondly, modern programming is all about [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) principle. So, the answer is **no**, you do not need to write the same piece of code for each of them.

You could actually do it at least two ways.
The first way would be to create some sort of collection of your textboxes (an [array](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/basics/arrays/), for example). Then you would create a method to iterate over this collection like this:

```
private bool AllTextboxesAreFilled()
{
    var textboxes = new TextBox[] { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3 };
    return textboxes.All(textbox => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.Text));
}
```

And then call it like:

```
if (!AllTextboxesAreFilled())
{
    MessageBox.Show("please fill in the boxes");
}
```

The second way would be to make these textboxes children of some control (a `Panel`, for example) and then iterate over these children. This way you don't need to create an additional collection (and to remember to add elements in it in case you need more textboxes):

```
private bool AllTextboxesAreFilled()
{
    return holderPanel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().All(textbox => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.Text));
}
```

The usage is the same as in the previous example.

Comment: it is better to use !String.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.Text) then textbox.Text != ""

Comment: @Nikita I agree with that, fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: Still,It takes care for null too. also, i prefer to use String.Empty over ""(constants are better than strings ).I really liked what you have suggested though :)

Comment: @_@ making my head hurt im barely beginner level here... Everytime i enter in the Private bool lines i get like 300 errors.... should i remove my if function already in place?

Comment: @KodySnow things that are like the ones under private bool lines are called functions (or also methods in case of C#). My guess is that you try to copy my function inside of your function, which is syntactically incorrect. You should write it straight inside the class (I guess, the form class in your case). To use methods like `All` and `OfType` you should also add the line `using System.Linq;` on the very top of the file where you write your code.