# How to Validate for Empty TextBoxes in Windows Forms Application?

Tags: c#, forms, validation, windows-forms-designer, is-empty

I'm new and just started trying out Windows Forms and I've managed to come up the following code for checking for empty textbox:

```
 public partial class form : Form
 {
      private string results;
 }

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      results = "";
      results += textBox1.Text;
      results += textBox2.Text;
      ...

      If (textBox1.Text == "") //I want to take this 'if' statement and turn it into a separate method called checkEmptyFields()
      {
           MessageBox.Show("This field cannot be left blank.");
           textBox1.Focus();
      }
      else { MessageBox.Show(results, "This is the results window");}
 }
```

Now, my problem comes when I will have 10+ textboxes (such as First Name, Last Name, Address, Email, etc.) that I will need my program to check if their fields have been left empty.  How do I take the 'if' statement and make that into another separate method something like **checkEmptyFields()**?

When I press the button1 to submit the form, that's when I want the checkEmptyFields() to trigger to check for any empty fields in textboxes and display an error message to warn the user.

Comment: see this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750290/how-can-i-check-multiple-textboxes-if-null-or-empty-without-a-unique-test-for-ea

Comment: You can also use built-in control validation: https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+forms+textbox+validation&ie=&oe=https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+forms+textbox+validation&ie=&oe=